# Why does const_cast not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, constants, copy-constructor

```
struct A
{
    A() {}

private:
    A(const A&); // Explicitly disable the copy constructor.
};

int main()
{
    const A a1; // OK.
    A       a2; // OK.
    auto    a3 = const_cast<A&>(a1); // Compiler error C2248! ???       
}
```

My C++ compiler is the latest VC++ 2013 preview.

The compiler complains for the last line with error C2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class 'A'

Why does const_cast not behave as expected?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`auto`, by itself, is never a reference type. So the last line is equivalent to

```
A a3 = const_cast<A&>(a1);
```

which attempts to copy `a1` using the private constructor.

If you want a reference, you need to specify a reference:

```
auto & a3 = const_cast<A&>(a1);
```

Of course, attempting to use this reference to modify `a1` will give undefined behaviour, since the object itself is `const`.

Comment: Is that means `const_cast` generate new objects?

Comment: @lulyon: No; the result of the `const_cast<A&>` is a reference to the existing object. Declaring an object generates a new object, and that's what `auto a = whatever;` does (whether or not `whatever` is a reference).